# Java generics with maps

Tags: java, generics

In the following code, line 14 fails to compile with error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from `Map<String,Set<Integer>>` to `Map<String,Set<? extends Number>>`

```
  1 import java.util.HashMap;
  2 import java.util.HashSet;
  3 import java.util.Map;
  4 import java.util.Set;
  5
  6 public class GenericTest
  7 {
  8     public static void main(String[] args)
  9     {
 10         Set<? extends Number> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
 11
 12         Map<String, Set<Integer>> intMap = new HashMap<>();
 13         Map<String, Set<? extends Number>> numberMap = intMap;
 14     }
 15 }
```

Is there any way to declare the numberMap so this compiles?

I know I can use `Map<String, Object>`, but I want to be able to retrieve values from the map as a set of numbers without having to cast.

Comment: See also: [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why are Java generics not implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/507738).